# How to make Beautifulsoup not adding <html> or <?xml ?>

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to let beautifulsoup not adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the beginning of a xml file or `<html> </html>` tag?

I've read [bs4 doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) and tried xml, html and lxml parser, but the results are similar. 
I also tested `soup.find('?xml')`, this returns nothing.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  2 2016, 04:20:16) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> xml='<tag>value</tag>'
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(xml,'xml')
>>> soup
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <=============== 
<tag>value</tag>
>>> soup.find('?xml')
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(xml,'html')
>>> soup
<html><body><tag>value</tag></body></html>  <===========
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(xml,'lxml')
>>> soup
<html><body><tag>value</tag></body></html>  <===========
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#You can directly print the tag (or body). Hope this helps.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml='<tag>value</tag>'
soup=BeautifulSoup(xml,'lxml')
soup.tag  #or soup.body

#Output:
<tag>value</tag>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is possible the only way to go.